# Use of static object of one class in the other

Tags: c++, class, static

I am trying to test calls for static object from one class in the other. I get here linking error **LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class K G::ob1"** I don't know what's wrong and on the internet I cannot find any info about static objects, only static with all other configurations. Therefore I ask for your help. Do I need to create object of K for this whole to work, or am I able to abstract so much that I don't create any objects?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class K
{
    int a;
public:
    K(int x) { a = x; };
    void print() {  cout << " a is: " << a << endl; };
};

class G
{
public:
    static K ob1;
    static void printG()
    {
        ob1.print();
    };
};

int main()
{
    K o1(10);
    G::printG();
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the static variable. It is similar to a global variable in C.

```
K G::ob1;
int main(){ .... }
```

Comment: It works, thank you (having added default constructor some value), but can you explain me why is this so? From what I understand I declared member variable of class G (being object of class K). Because it's static I don't need an instance of class G. **WHY cannot I do it in main() as I tried?**

Comment: The class body DECLARES your class variable but doesn't INITIALIZE it.

Comment: @beginh also note you could do `K G::ob1(10); int main(){}`

Comment: @poljpocket yes I know, but just cannot grasp idea why the class static variable needs to be initialized in the global scope (before main)

Comment: When you do it in main you are trying to declare and initialize, but it is already declared so it doesn't know what to do, I believe .

Comment: IDK why exactly but the standard does state "The definition for a static data member shall appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition."